# How can I change the output of getZonedTime to a string with the format "Year-Month-Day" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

The output of findCurrentTime1 function in the following code snippet is: 2021-06-28 22:43:22.923841508 UTC.

How do I turn this into a string with the format "Year-Month-Day" in Haskell?

```
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.Time.Calendar


findCurrentTime1 = do
  zt <- getZonedTime
  print zt

main = do
  findCurrentTime1
```

Here, I am trying to convert a getZonedTime value to a string.

What I have tried fail to compile.

1. zt = fmap show getZonedTime
2. zt <- fmap show getZonedTime
3. (y, m, d) <$> getZonedTime
4. The following code snippet.

```
  zt <- getZonedTime
  let timeFromString = readTime defaultTimeLocale "%d %b %Y %l:%M %p" zt :: UTCTime
  print zt
```

5. formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d" zt
6. I tried using show and take the first 10 characters, and I got a compilation error. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68170959/1531728.

parse error on input `='

So, I changed the "=" to a "<-". And, I end up with another compilation error.

```
zt <- getZonedTime
  s1 <- show zt
  s2 <- take 10 s1
  print s2
```

Comment: Are you on the same course as this q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68157721/how-to-parse-timezone-offset-with-seconds? What have you tried so far? This isn't a service to write code for you.

Comment: No, it's different, since getZonedTime seems to return a value of the Date type, as opposed to a string.

What I have tried fail to compile.

1) zt = fmap show getZonedTime

2) zt <- fmap show getZonedTime

3) (y, m, d) <$> getZonedTime

```
zt <- getZonedTime
  let timeFromString = readTime defaultTimeLocale "%d %b %Y %l:%M %p" zt :: UTCTime
  print zt
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `formatTime` snippet looks right.  This works for example:

```
import Data.Time

main :: IO ()
main = do zt <- getZonedTime
          putStrLn (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d" zt)
```

Or the same thing but naming the string:

```
main = do zt <- getZonedTime
          let s = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d" zt
          putStrLn s
```

Another way to get the string would be `(showGregorian . localDay . zonedTimeToLocalTime) zt`.  (Or `show` actually does the same thing as `showGregorian`.)

I've assumed you want the local date - for UTC date it would be `(showGregorian . utctDay . zonedTimeToUTC) zt`.

Answer (score 1):

Running in the **ghci**:

```hs
x <- getZonedTime -- x: ZonedTime
s = show x        -- s: String (Ex: "2021-06-28 20:15:15.937914201 -03")
take 10 s         -- "2021-06-28"
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, it's only one solution.

I recommend you try to use your basic knowledge of types in Haskell and try to use the [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=ZonedTime%20-%3E%20String). With the basics, you can create all you want.

- Edit #1

A valid Haskell script must be:

```hs
module Main where

import Data.Time

main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- getZonedTime
  let s = show x
  print $ take 10 s
```

Comment: I tried it and I got a compilation error.

parse error on input `='

So, I changed the "=" to a "<-". And, I end up with another compilation error.

```
zt <- getZonedTime
  s1 <- show zt
  s2 <- take 10 s1
  print s2
```

Comment: Into a Monad context, like "IO ()", all "variable <- function" is used to execute an "IO a" function that will return a variable with type "a". Use "let" to execute a normal function call that was not in a monad context, in this case, an IO context.

Answer (score 0):

This builds upon the answer in: [Daniel Farina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68170959/1531728).

It takes the value of the Day type and turns it into a string, finds the first 10 characters of this Day value as a substring, prints the substring stored as a variable, and returns the substring via the aforementioned variable.

I made this modification to use the result of the function call in subsequent operations.

```
import Data.Time

findCurrentTime3a = do
  zt <- getZonedTime
  let s1 = show zt
  let s2 = take 10 s1
  print s2
  return s2

main = do
  result <- findCurrentTime3a
  print result
```